# Alinear Iconos de Font Awesome y texto

Tags: html, css, html5

me gustaría saber si alguien se le ocurre como puedo alinear tres iconos o fonts, pero deben estar en horizontal con un espacios entre ellos y poderse adaptar a los distintos tipos de dispositivos móviles y otros, lo comento, puesto que no he podido lograrlo y necesito ayuda.

```css
 .info {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
 .info i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1977cc;
  float: left;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background: #d6e9fa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

 .info h4 {
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #2c4964;
}

 .info p {
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4b7dab;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="info">
              <div class="address">
                <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i>
                <h4>Location:</h4>
                <p>KIST Hospital Road, 44700</p>
              </div>

              <div class="email">
                <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
                <h4>Email:</h4>
                <p>prcare@example.com</p>
              </div>

              <div class="phone">
                <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
                <h4>Call:</h4>
                <p>+1 55234 5112 33s</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Esto me podría ayudar a entender de mejor manera como alinear los elementos, ya que están tres iconos metidos en un contenedor y la idea es que sean lo más adaptativos y responsivos posibles, de tal manera que el contenido se puede apreciar de buena manera desde un ordenador hasta un dispositivo móvil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una mejor opción sería utilizar las [**rejillas**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) del framework Bootstrap.

Para usarlo, debemos crear un nuevo `div` con la clase `row`, en donde indicamos que será una fila, y dentro de esa fila estarán las rejillas.

Las rejillas de Bootstrap tienen un límite del ancho de `12`, por la cual, para que los 3 elementos ocupen todo el ancho, dividamos sus rejillas con un ancho de `4`.

Los anchos de las rejillas se definen así:

```
col-md-4 col-12
```

En donde indico que tus 3 elementos ocupan el ancho de `4` hasta superar el ancho de la pantalla en `md` (los anchos puedes verlo [**aquí**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)). Una vez superemos el ancho del `md`, continuamos al siguiente `col`, que es justamente el `12`, en donde tus 3 elementos ocuparán el ancho máximo, posicionándose 1 debajo del otro.

Entonces, tu estructura HTML quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```css
.info {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
.info i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1977cc;
  float: left;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background: #d6e9fa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.info h4 {
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #2c4964;
}

.info p {
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4b7dab;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="info">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="address col-md-4 col-12">
        <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i>
        <h4>Location:</h4>
        <p>KIST Hospital Road, 44700</p>
      </div>
      <div class="email col-md-4 col-12">
        <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
        <h4>Email:</h4>
        <p>prcare@example.com</p>
      </div>
      <div class="phone col-md-4 col-12">
        <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
        <h4>Call:</h4>
        <p>+1 55234 5112 33s</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/poxRbvE).